# People Search from Advanced Search

Tags: search-results

I have enabled the Advanced Search with multiple scopes as follows.

- All Sites
- People
- Projects
- Communities

User can select mulitple scopes and hit the search button. He is redirected to the Search results page with "All Sites" highlighted(As this is the default and root site collection).Let say, if I select the scope of "People" to search for the people. I want to highlight only with the People tab in the search results page. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The standard "search result" page (results.aspx) and the "people search result" (peopleresults.aspx) pages are 2 different pages. You can always add extra controls or CSS files to these pages if you want to.

Comment: I could not highlight the people on the results.aspx page.

Comment: You want to highlight the "people" word on the result page? Add a CSS file to the page that defines your desired highlight

Comment: I want to highlight all the selected scopes of the site collection

Comment: Could some one help me please? I am trying to override the click event of the Search button in the Advanced Search Web Part to identfy the check boxes with the ids $ASB_SS_scb_0_1,
$ASB_SS_scb_1_0,
$ASB_SS_scb_2_4,
$ASB_SS_scb_3_5,
$ASB_SS_scb_4_6

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using SharePoint 2013. You would have to run JavaScript on the Advanced Search page that conditionally directs the user to PeopleResults.aspx if they choose the People vertical.